# cannot connect to socket.io server from React Native app when using expo on iPhone

Tags: react-native, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

for some reason I can connect to the server from the browser, but not from an iPhone. Anyone know why? I have a feeling it has something to do with SSL certs but I can't find a solution online that works.

server:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_json(json):
    print('CONNECTED')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

client:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

var socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:5000/")

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> test </Text>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    );
  }
  
}

export default App
```

Comment: what's the error or warning that shows up when you try to do your connection?

Comment: when I add, 
`socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {  console.log("connect_error due to " + err.message});});` 
I continually get a 
`connect_error due to xhr poll error`

Comment: This is an example using Node js. You can try to configure from server side ```socketIo(server, { rejectUnauthorized: false, ...}``` but if you do this, you will be vulnerable to MITM attacks

Answer (score 0):

Is server and iPhone in same network ? If not maybe ur server's firewall rules does not allows to request. iOS on default does not allows http(not secure) requests. You must change ur info.plist file u must add NSAppTransportSecurity key.